# Terraform 0.14, Validate variable base on the value of another variable

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

Is there a way of implementing the logic like I have to check the condition for both variables i.e env and subscription id. It should skip the execution for dev env and continue for stg and prod. I was trying the below code:

```
locals {
   validate_env_code_cnd = var.env == "dev" && var.subscription_id == "XXX"
   validate_env_code_msg = "The environment should not dev for given sub"
   validate_env_code_chk = regex (
        "^${local.validate_env_code_msg}$",
        (!local.validate_env_code_cnd 
         ? local.validate_env_code_msg 
         : "") )
```

I am getting the error like:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on vars.tf line 20, in locals:
  20:   validate_env_code_chk = regex("^${local.validate_env_code_msg}$", 
   (!local.validate_env_code_cnd ? local.validate_env_code_msg : "") )
    |----------------
    | local.validate_env_code_cnd is true
    | local.validate_env_code_msg is "The dev environment not allowed for given 
    sub"

  Call to function "regex" failed: pattern did not match any part of the given
  string.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working is `validate_env_code_cnd` is returing `true` or `false` but you want actual values. This should work for your use case.

```
variable "env" {
  default = "dev"
}

variable "subscription_id" {
  default = "XXX"
}

locals {
   validate_env_code_msg = "The environment should not dev for given sub"
   validate_env_code_chk = length(regexall(var.env, local.validate_env_code_msg)) > 0 && length(regexall(var.subscription_id, local.validate_env_code_msg)) > 0
  
   validate_env_code_updated = var.env == "dev" && var.subscription_id == "XXX" ? local.validate_env_code_msg : ""
}

output "test" {
  value = local.validate_env_code_chk
}

output "test_updated" {
  value = local.validate_env_code_updated
}
```

I am returning `True` or `False` but you can return anything or check and continue.

Comment: I don't want actual values. Instead of validate_env_code_cnd will check the condition, if it is true then and then it should throw the error msg.

Comment: @trvar try now. I have updated the answer to cover both the cases. Let me know if you still have questions